# Convert HTML to pptx4j elements

Tags: java, html, powerpoint, docx4j

I've successfully implemented the use of the XHTMLImporter class of docx4j to convert XHMTL into docx4j (Word) elements. However, I now need to do the same thing for pptx4j (Powerpoint), but after *much* searching and trial-and-error, there doesn't appear to be anything corresponding to the XHTMLImporter for pptx4j, nor does it appear to be possible to take the docx4j-element results of the XHTMLImporter and append them to pptx4j Shapes.

Has anyone solved this problem for pptx4j? And/or, can anyone point me to a library or source code I could use to perform this task?

Thanks!

Carl

Answer (score 0):

**Disclosure: I maintain docx4j**

You would have to copy and alter the XHTMLImporter code, so that it emits DrawingML instead of WordML. A little tedious, but eminently do-able.

Comment: I was afraid of that, since while certainly doable, it's not trivial; so I was _really_ hoping someone had already done it for me! (And I can't be the first person to need to format HTML into a pptx4j document!) But thanks for the quick reply, in any event!